# Python: Is there a better way for read()?

Tags: python-2.7

In the following code I am about to create a temp file and then save the entire content of a txt file in this temp file. This is just a example. I know that makes no sense to read a text file and then write it in the temp file. But I want to demonstrate my question.

Well when I use the read() metod that means the entire contens of the temp file is saved in the RAM memory, right? I can't control the content size of the temp file. So I thinking about if there is a better way to protect the RAM memory. I don't want to inundate the RAM memory.

```
# Use the TemporaryFile context manager for easy clean-up
with tempfile.TemporaryFile(delete=True) as tmp:
    with open('filename.txt', 'r') as my_file:
        for line in my_file:
            tmp.write(line)

    tmp.seek(0)

    exec(tmp.read())
```

Comment: the code does not correspond to the text description. What is your actual task? Do you want to execute a text file as a Python code (judging by `exec(tmp.read())` in your code) or do you want to copy the content of one text file into another one line by line (judging by `for line in file: output_file.write(line)` in your code). What is your actual question?

Comment: @ J.F. Sebastian; You're right. I want to execute a text file as a Python code. In this case a code is saved in a text file. But later I will save the text file on a Web server. My program accesses the text file, saves it in the temp file and then execute it.

Comment: then why are you worrying about RAM? are you running it on a micro-controller? How much RAM is available? You are not afraid to run arbitrary code from the internet but you worry that there is too much code? What the code does? Does it make sense to run it a line at a time (with a clear namespace). If you are reading data from the network; you may stop whenever you like for whatever reason.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: Currently Its just an idea and experiment. My idea is: When a user logs on my web server with my program, my program will (after a successful log in) access to a special text file that is stored on my web server. I want to save all content of this online text file in a temp file and then I want to execute it. That said, its just an idea and experiment.

Comment: I didn't mean to criticize. I understand **how** you do it (get a file via http, save it as a temporary file, read it back immediately as a string, use `exec()` to run it as Python code). I do not understand **what** you're trying to do (not how) and **why** you do it that way. You have asked the question: "better way for read()"--without a very specific context, it is unclear what type of answer you expect. For example, why do you need a temporary file? You can read directly from the network and pass `size` argument to `.read()`, to limit the total amount read.

Comment: I thougt its better way for performance when the program saves the online text file as a temp file, because when the script connects via http to a file (for example with requets module) then it will download the file at first. So I think the downloading of the file could flood the memory. And when I save the online file as a temp file I don't need the network connection anymore.

Comment: it looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096): you are asking "how to read a temporary file without consuming all the memory" (a possible answer is: use `.read(limit)` instead of `.read()` or read line by line or read in chunks). What you should ask: "how do I read Python code from the network without consuming all the memory" (you should at least mention: why you think you need to read the code from the network and whether you need to execute it all at once or e.g., may the code be executed line by line?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for line in my_file` calls the file objects `.next` which [does not buffer the entire file in memory when reading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next):

> In order to make a for loop the most efficient way of looping over the
>   lines of a file (a very common operation), the next() method uses a
>   hidden read-ahead buffer

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This
>   is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code

For the `tmp.read()` function, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> When size is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will
>   be read and returned; it’s your problem if the file is twice as large
>   as your machine’s memory.

So unless you read by line as you do when you write, or `read` with a fixed amount incrementally *i.e* `tmp.read(100)`, you will read the entire file into memory.

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't understood my question, because my focus is on the read () method, that is nested in the exec() method. Look, after the created temp file has been filled, I am about to use the exec() method. In this context I am using the read() method. And now I am thinking about if the read () method flooded the RAM memories?

Comment: You can always read(SomeFixedAmount) until you have read the entire file if you do not want to read line by line, although you should just read line by line again if you need to read?